# USB modem not working after I installed some package

Tags: ubuntu, modem, mobile

I have a DWM-156 D-Link modem on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Everything was fine before I installed `telephony-service 0.1+14.04.20140415-0ubuntu1` SMS and Call manager. Now OS doesn't show modem connection in Network Manager, whereas `lsusb` shows the USB dongle like this:

```
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 2001:7d01 D-Link Corp.
```

And `demsg` output:

```
sensor@sensor:~$ dmesg | tail
[ 1812.265041] usbserial_generic 2-3:1.4: The "generic" usb-serial driver is only for testing and one-off prototypes. 
[ 1812.265045] usbserial_generic 2-3:1.4: Tell linux-usb@vger.kernel.org to add your device to a properdriver. 
[ 1812.265049] usbserial_generic 2-3:1.4: generic converter detected 
[ 1812.265122] usb 2-3: generic converter now attached to ttyUSB2 
[ 1812.265660] usbserial_generic 2-3:1.5: The "generic" usb-serial driver is only for testing and one-off prototypes.
[1812.265665] usbserial_generic 2-3:1.5: Tell linux-usb@vger.kernel.org to add your device to a proper driver.
[ 1812.265668]usbserial_generic 2-3:1.5: generic converter detected 
[ 1812.265752]usb 2-3: generic converter now attached to ttyUSB3 
[ 1812.266285]usb-storage 2-3:1.6: USB Mass Storage device detected 
[ 1812.266383]scsi12 : usb-storage 2-3:1.6
```

And this is my kernel version:

```
sensor@sensor:~$ uname -a
Linux sensor 3.13.0-35-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 15 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Now I am removing that SMS (`telephony-service`) application, but the problem still exists. Suggest me how I can fix the problem please.

Comment: Try to check via [lsof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof), what program holds one of the ttyUSB* opened.